# How to exclude Jquery mouseup for a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

I have this piece of code in my page

```
<body onmouseup="fun()">
.......
.......
<button id="ele">Exclude</button>

</body>
```

How can i achieve something like this

```
function fun()
{
    if(MOUSE RELEASE IS ON TOP OF BUTTON #ele)
    {
        console.log('Mouse released on top of the button');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('Mouse released');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just bind the event you need for the element(s) you need?

Comment: There are lot of elements...and lot of code restructuring as this is an old project..any other alternatives @Lee Taylor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using jQuery I would suggest using `.on()` to bind events. You can use the `event.target` element to see if it was the button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('mouseup', fun);
    function fun(event){
        if($(event.target).is('#ele')){
             console.log('Mouse released on top of the button');
        }else{
            console.log('Mouse released');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Where is that `element` comes from

Comment: Thankyou will check and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.stopPropagation`, like this:

html

```
<button id="ele">Exclude</button>
<br>
<br>
<div>fun</div>
```

js

```
document.body.onmouseup = function(){ fun(); };
function fun(){
 console.log("fun");   
}
var el = document.getElementById("ele");
el.onmouseup = function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); };
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GgKsQ/

and here is a demo using jQuery's `mouseup`: http://jsfiddle.net/GgKsQ/1/

Answer (score 1):

This is an orthodox code it gives you what you required.
please copy into your editor and check.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onmouseup="fun()">
The content of the body element is displayed in your browser.
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div id="Exclude" onmousedown="fun2()"> Exclude Me Please </div>
</body>
<script>
var idPressed = 0;
function fun() {
if (idPressed == 0)
console.log('Mouse released');
idPressed = 0;
//alert("Whatever "+this.id);
}

function fun2() {
idPressed = 1;
console.log('Mouse released 2');
//alert("Whatever 2"+this.id);
}

</script>
</html>
```